# Undefined index: id

Tags: php, base-de-datos, buscador

Estoy intentando hacer un buscador bastante básico con `PHP`, pero estoy recibiendo el siguiente error, no se que puede ser, los campos que tengo en mi base de datos son "Id", "nombre", "fechayhora"  y ya, eso son mis valores en mi base de datos `phpmyadmin`

---BUSCAR.PHP---

```
<?php 
    include("conexion2.php");
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

    mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db_nombre) or die("Error al conectar con la base de datos");

    $registros=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE id=$id");

    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
        echo ($registro['id']." ".$registro['nombre']." ".$registro['fechayhora']);
    }
?>
```

---CONEXION2.PHP---

```
<?php
     $db_host="localhost";
     $db_usuario="jesus";
     $db_contra="jesus";
     $db_nombre="bd_prueba";
     $conexion=new mysqli($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);

     if($conexion){
         echo("Conecto");
     }
     else{
         echo("No se concecto a la base de datos");
     }
     mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
 ?>
```

---formBusqueda.php---

```
<?php include("conexion2.php") ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Buscar</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="buscar.php " method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Ingrese codigo a buscar">
            <input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿`formBusqueda.php` y `buscar.php` están en la misma carpeta?

Comment: Chi, estan en la carpeta dentro del servidor

Comment: ¿Preguntaba si están los dos **en la misma carpeta**? Y haz una depuración del POST, en `buscar.php` pon esto `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.